# redirecting url through htaccess by masking it

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have two domains, www.domainA.com and www.domainB.com. I have actual files in domainA.com/files. When a user go to www.domainB.com, he should redirect to www.domainA.com/files. but in address bar it should show www.domainB.com.

I do not know how to do it. Somebody please suggest me how to achieve this.

*** EDITED *****

I have downloaded proxy script from http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpr0xi/ and did the same think in .htaccess, but it gives me below error.
**404 Not Found
The server can not find the requested page:**

my .htaccess in www.domainB.com.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^domainb(.*) http://www.domainA.com/domainb$1 [P]
```

Comment: You cannot do this without a proxy in place on domainB to retrieve files from domainA and serve the contents.  A change of domain _must_ imply a redirect to the new domain; silent redirection isn't possible.

Comment: Are both vhosts on the same webserver? If they're on different machines, do you have mod_proxy available?

Comment: ...Unless of course, those two domains reside on the same server and you can simply point domainB at domainA's files....

Comment: yes, both the domain on the same server and mod_proxy is enabled. Please look into my edited post above

Comment: We can neither guess request urls, server setup nor directory layout from the little information you gave.

Comment: i am not getting what all the info i need to provide :(. sorry

Answer (score 0):

You can try this [htaccess redirect](http://htaccessredirect301.com), it should generate this code for you for a 302 redirect.

```
#302 Redirect Entire Old directories
RedirectMatch 302 domainb(.*) http://www.domainA.com/domainb$1
```

since you want to keep the old domain on the address bar, the 302 redirect code will do the trick

Comment: i gave `RewriteEngine on

RedirectMatch 302 domainb(.*) http://www.domainA.com/domainb$1 `, it redirects to domain but in address bar it shows domain b name only :(